# Try-Catch does not catch errors from "System.setProperty"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, I added the code below to see if I am using a wrong Chrome driver,

```
  try {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Chrome Drivers\\chromedriverLinux32");
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(1);
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
```

but whenever it happens, the test throws:

```
Jan 14, 2016 11:04:25 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForErrorSEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\sina\Desktop\WorkSpace\CowZAllPages\Chrome Drivers\chromedriverLinux32" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)
```

But the catch does catch any errors (`System.out.println(1);` is not seen).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code in the way you assign the Chrome Path.
The System literally gets that string. 

You'll want to have a look at the driver initialization and put a try-catch there, in order to catch such exceptions.

**Update:**
Perhaps you need to revise this use case - in the sense that you can have 3 ChromeDriver paths and use the right one depending on the platform.

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

This way, you'll always use the right ChromeDriver.

Comment: I also added try-catch for `driverChrome = new hromeDriver(capabilities);`   but it does not get the error too :(

Comment: which line from your code is causing the exception? that would be step #1 to start with.

Comment: Hmmm I figured out that it's being caused by `driverChrome = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);`  but `Exception e`  cannot catch it !!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. but I still need to know why my catch could not get the error